# Shacl Specification Error or just confusing, i am missing something?

Tags: shacl

Taken from the specification:

> **A node shape** is a shape in the shapes graph that is **not the subject of**
> **a triple with sh:path as its predicate**.  SHACL instances of
> sh:NodeShape cannot have a value for the property sh:path.

Yet when talking about Or Constraint or And Constraint, that takes list of shapes, we find example like what follow:

```
ex:SuperShape a sh:NodeShape ;
   sh:property [ sh:path ex:property ; sh:minCount 1 ; ] .

ex:ExampleAndShape a sh:NodeShape ; 
   sh:targetNode ex:ValidInstance, ex:InvalidInstance ; 
   sh:and ( 
           ex:SuperShape 
           [ 
             sh:path ex:property ; 
             sh:maxCount 1 ; 
           ] ) .
```

With the following explanation

> The following example illustrates the use of sh:and in a shape to
> specify the condition that certain focus nodes have exactly one value
> of ex:property. This is achieved via the conjunction of a separate
> named shape (ex:SuperShape) which specifies the minimum count, and a
> **blank node** shape that additionally specifies the maximum count. As
> shown here, sh:and can be used to implement a specialization mechanism
> between shapes.

How on earth is this a Blank Node shape if it is the subject of an sh:path, am I missing something ?

```
 [ 
    sh:path ex:property ; 
    sh:maxCount 1 ; 
 ]
```

Can someone help me understand what i am probably missing here ?

Comment: This question has meanwhile been answered at https://groups.google.com/g/topbraid-users/c/WAEORiyXAls